# Unable to load image from HTTPS url in android

Tags: android

Till this date my app was using the images from an http site and the site is now being upgraded to https . So here comes the issue, now my app does not shows the images at al even though my url is updated. Please look at my current code and help me.

Thanks,
Yoga.

Code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String URL =
    "https://googledrive.com/host/0B_DiX4MiMa3HTHdiYVRmUHBMcW8/image1.jpg";
ImageView imageView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);

    // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    // Execute the task
    task.execute(new String[] { URL });
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        System.out.println("finished");
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpsURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: But this **https://example.com/image1.jpg** shows SSL error. Nothing displayed.

Comment: Probably because that's not a real URL. She replaced the real one

Comment: Added proper https url. please check now

Comment: Did you get any error?? Have you add internet permission also?

Comment: Yeah i have internet permission and there are no error thats what makes me confusing

Comment: Change this from   bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1; to   bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;

Comment: can you explain piyush?

Comment: Because looking your image url your image is very high resolution so need to change so it will be decoded as per that sample size.

Comment: I have tried that also and it doesnt display the image

Comment: Did You got solution.. if so kindly post the answer, me also suffering from same problem

Comment: @Bindhu i switched over to http mode since https take long time to load than https and moreover our team decided that the content is not that important so we decided to stick with http

Answer (score 0):

use **[HttpsURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)** instead of **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)** for https connections

---

**Update:** I just checked the url of your image and it returned status `304` instead `200`

> Request
>   URL:https://googledrive.com/host/0B_DiX4MiMa3HTHdiYVRmUHBMcW8/image1.jpg
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:304 Not Modified

==> Try handling the status HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED instead of HTTP_OK. Or just handle both cases:

```
if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK ||
    httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED ) {

      stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
} else { // just in case..
      log.wtf("Surprize!", "HTTP status was: " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
}
```

see documentation about [http status 304 Not Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is
>   allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD
>   respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a
>   message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.

Comment: will give a try and let you know the result in a while

Comment: It dint work @donfuxx. Please see my updated code and let me know what else needs to be updated

Comment: Did you also try the handling the http 304 like in the update?

Comment: yes. just now tried and this too doesnt seem to work... is thre any other way to get image from https site

Comment: log the value of `httpConnection.getResponseCode()` like in my updated answer. Maybe Google Drive blocks requests that are not from a browser

Comment: log says "03-15 09:40:43.034: I/System.out(1842): Surprize0!HTTP status was:org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$LimitedInputStream@43e9b3a8
"

Comment: OK, I put wrong output in log message. Try again with `log.wtf("Surprize!", "HTTP status was: " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());` to see the status code actually.

Comment: http status was : 200

Comment: Lol that is weird. In theory if http status is 200 then the else block should not have been executed.. and if I open your image in browser I see http status 304.

Comment: yeah.it is rattling my head. planning to use webview instead of all these stuffs

Answer (score 0):

```
  {

     trustEveryone();
    // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    //your image url
    String url = "https://thepoprewards.com.au/uploads/user_image/1514370542.jpg";

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .build();


    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options);
}
```

After write this code now write the method **trustEveryone**

```
  private void trustEveryone() {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }});
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {}
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }}}, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                context.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: **THIS IS DANGEROUS** and disables SSL verification entirely!  Do not do this!